# I can't seem to concatenate two strings together in the append() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

```js
$('resultsBlue').append('<p><b>Verschil: </b>' + (randomNumber1 - randomNumber) / 1000 + ' Seconden</p>');
```

```css
#resultsBlue {
  background-color: #6699ff;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.resultDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='resultsBlue' class='Div'>
  <h1>Blauw</h1>
</div>
```

That's a snippet of all of the code that has to do with this issue

As you can see in the snippet, I'm trying to append multiple data types but it just doesn't seem to work. How do I get it to do what I want? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put `#` in the selector.

`$('#resultsBlue').append('<p><b>Verschil: </b>' + (randomNumber1 - randomNumber) / 1000 + ' Seconden</p>');`

Comment: O.O.... I have been trying to solve it for three hours now. Thank you anyway haha.

Comment: @Jojo, sometime we face this kind of situation. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it helps----Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepend an `#` for the id.

I think

`$('resultsBlue').append('<p><b>Verschil: </b>' + (20 - 10) / 1000 + ' Seconden</p>');`

should be

`$('#resultsBlue').append('<p><b>Verschil: </b>' + (20 - 10) / 1000 + ' Seconden</p>');`

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#resultsBlue')` since you're selecting an element which has an `id` property.